# Is there a way to change pitch of local engine text-to-speech voice in python

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pitch

I am using text-to-speech in my python project but not getting any way to increase or decrease the pitch 
level of the local machine voice in python. Here is my basic code:

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import random


print("Intializing Toretto")

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty('rate', 210)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 2):

Pyttx3 fortunately do not strip xml sapi tags on Windows.
You can use them like this

```
engine.say('<pitch middle="10">Hello there!</pitch>')
```

It depends on your TTS engine which tags are supported though.

https://www.clarosoftware.com/help/using-microsoft-xml-tags-with-sapi5/

Answer (score 1):

you should add a getProperty for the rate like this:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty('rate', 210)
```